# New Div acting weird? Not showing Up?

Tags: css, class, html

Okay guys so I have created multiple div classes, and they seem to work. But when I want to add another div class underneath them, it just doesn't show up.

Here's my html code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--LINKING THE STYLESHEETS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--DO NOT EDIT THIS STYLE SHEET-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
<style>
html, body {min-width: 600px; background-image: url(bg.jpg);}

/*Navigation Bar*/
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image: url(nav_bg.png);  background-repeat: repeat;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
width: 50em;
height: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
ul.nav {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 1em;
width: 80%;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
}
li
{
display:inline;
text-align: center;
margin: 30px;

}
.nav a {
line-height:50px;
}

@font-face {
font-family: corbel;
src: url('fonts/corbel.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: orator;
src: url('fonts/OratorStd.otf');
}
/*CUSTOMIZING THE LINKS*/
a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: corbel;
font-size: 18px;
}
a:visited {
color: #fff;
}
a:active {
color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
color: #111;
}
/*THE CONTAINERS*/
.box-long {
width: 80%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 1em;
}
.box-half-long {
width: 39.4%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: 9.9%;
margin-top: 1em;
float: left;
}
.box-half-long-r {
width: 39.4%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: 50.5%;
margin-top: 1em;
}
/*Keeping images in containers even when browser resizes. */
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
/*styling headers*/
h1.center {
text-align: center;
line-height: 110px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
font-family: orator;
}
h2.center {
text-align: center;
line-height: 110px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
font-family: orator;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="box-long">
<h1 class="center">SERVER BANNER HERE</h1>
<!--YOU COULD AD AN IMAGE HERE. REMOVE THIS COMMENT AND DELETE THE <H1> TAGS TO SEE
IT WORKING WITH AN IMAGE. IMAGE SIZE IS -->
<!-- REMOVE ME FOR IMAGE // <img src="server_banner.jpg"> // -->
</div>

<div class="box-half-long">
<h2 class="center">SUB-CAT 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="box-half-long-r">
<h2 class="center">SUB-CAT 2</h2>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's the site this code is on: [here](http://mc-template.uk.to)

So, when I go ahead and add a new div class at the end, for example, this; (p.s, yes I know the div hasn't been set up in css, this is just a demonstation..)

```
    .box-newdiv{
width: 80%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 1em;
}
```

It just doesn't show up?

EDIT: Link is now working to view.

Comment: Your link appears to require authentication.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an HTML element with class "box-newdiv", but your CSS definition doesn't get applied to it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the problem. I don't see the new `<div>` or its CSS definition in your live page. What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: The Div I am trying to add underneath the previous div, simply isn't showing. Thanks, also the link is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't see the new div's is because you have provided fixed height for the div having the classes named  as "box-half-long" and "box-half-long-r".

```
    .box-half-long-r {
width: 39.4%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: 50.5%;
margin-top: 1em;
}

.box-half-long {
width: 39.4%;
height: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 2px;
margin-left: 9.9%;
margin-top: 1em;
float: left;
}
```

Since they have a fixed height, they don't show the elements contained in them which lie below the height of 100px.

Let the height 'adapt' to the height of the containing elements. You can do this by:

```
height :auto;
```

Just change these classes to:

```
.box-half-long-r {
    width: 39.4%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-left: 50.5%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    }

    .box-half-long {
    width: 39.4%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-left: 9.9%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    float: left;
    }
```

I have added new div's to show that they can be displayed once you change the hieght to auto.

Just see here : http://jsfiddle.net/Bj3vr/

Hope this helps you to understand the concept of using "height as auto" and solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks! This was a major nuisance for me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the example but first thing I noticed is

```
.box-long {
height: 100px;
```

This could be why

EDIT:
Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4rhAz/

Comment: I couldn't see the example so I figured maybe the height being only 100px could hide divs that pass that 100px point